# Adding activity indicator to the detail view of a splitview controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm developing a splitview based application.I have three detailviewcontrollers which will be shown in the detailview section of the splitviewcontroller based on the selected row of rootviewcontroller.

All these detailviewcontrollers are tableviews which fetches data from the server.Hence while selecting a row in the rootviewcontroller,it is taking some time to load the respective detailview.I want to show an activity indicator in the detailview till the next view is  loaded.Can anybody help me??Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here (MBProgressHUD)](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) you have a progress indicator that is very easy to integrate into code and very flexible not to say handy in programming applications for the iPhone, it is called MBProgressHUD. If you don't like it you can always use the NetworkActivity indicator that is already on the iphone.

Comment: :Thank you for your reply.But the problem is regarding the viewcontroller to which I'm adding the indicator.The view in the detailview part of the splitviewcontroller is showing till the next view is loaded.I tried to add the indicator to this but the app is crashing showing: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MBProgressHUDViewIsNillException', reason: 'The view used in the MBProgressHUD initializer is nil.' ". Any idea?

Comment: From what I understand you are not initializing properly the MBProgressHUD. I tis telling you that it is nil therefore it can't show it. You are trying to access an object(MBProgressHUDView) that is not yet existant. Can you post the code you are using`??

Comment: Here is the code:   photoDetail *detail=[[photoDetail alloc]init];
 HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
 [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
 
 HUD.delegate = self;
 HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
 
 [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(viewDidLoad) onTarget:detail withObject:nil animated:YES];

Comment: u are using it on which viewDidLoad?

Comment: But what is the upcoming viewDidLoad? What is the purpose of that view? Does it fetch data? What does it do?

Comment: In my first viewcontroller,there will be some thumbnails.while clicking on the thumbnail, the second viewcontroller will be loaded.The second viewcontroller will fetch a series of fullscreen image data from the server and stores it into an array and displays it.The second view is loading only after all the image data is fetched.Hence I want to show the loading indicator till the second view is loaded.

Comment: Then select the method for the indicator as the one that fetches the fulscreen images. While the images are not fetched the indicator will continue to show.

Comment: I tried it.But not working.The problem is the second view is showing only after all the images are loaded.Till then,the first view will be visible.I tried to place the indicator in both the views but getting "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MBProgressHUDViewIsNillException', reason: 'The view used in the MBProgressHUD initializer is nil.' " in console.Anyway, thank you for your valuable help Mr.Joze.

Comment: Try fetching the images the moment you click on the thumbnail and putting the indicator there. when the indicator finishes the second view will be shown with the images already loaded. Try that. I have never had that exception so I'm a bit out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

check [lazy table images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394) code sample for a very very neat implementation ...